# Getting an error but working

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Im getting an error using my code on chrome using tampermonkey. I'd really like it to not show additional numbers aka errors. The error occuring is Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null but code is working.

```html
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Chrome Remove recent tabs
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      .1
// @description  Removes recently visited tabs
// @author       You
// @match        https://*/*
// ==/UserScript==

var del = document.getElementById('most-visited');
del.parentNode.removeChild(del);
```

Comment: The error tells you explicitly what is going on. Your selector does not match any element. `null`

Comment: `var del = document.getElementById('most-visited') == null` The object is not being found on the page.

Comment: You need `waitForKeyElements`, or similar.